Android Kotlin Jetpack Compose - Track down Keyboard's Down Arrow Button
This might be the duplicate question or may have been asked several times. I have tried to search the solution by other stack overflow answers but I don't seem to find the exact solution that works with me. I have an OutlineTextField and I am trying to work on with the down arrow button what I simply want is when I press that down arrow it should remove the focus from the textField as well. It simply dismiss the soft keyboard. I am trying to find a listener or any overwritten method where I can trigger that down arrow button and put my code focusManager.clearFocus(). I have similar action onDone KeyboardAction. Any help is appreciated.
I have tried BackHandler and onKeyEvent overridden method as well as the textField modifier's onKeyEvent method but nothing seems to be triggered on arrow down click.

Try this, use your code inside KeyboardActions
 var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
 val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
 OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    label = { Text("Label") },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext = {
        if (!focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down))
            focusManager.clearFocus()
    }),
    singleLine = true
 )

